# ASP.NET MVC and Mongodb references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have problem with my application. In my simple blog application I have Post and Category collection: 
Post.cs

```
public class Post 
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId PostId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ObjectId CategoryId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("WYSIWYG")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int TotalComments { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and category.cs

```
 public class Category
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

PostControler:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            post.Url = post.Title.GenerateSlug();
            post.Author = User.Identity.Name;
            post.Date = DateTime.Now;
            post.CategoryId = 
            _postService.Create(post);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

When I create new post, I want to choose category from list and save "_id" of category in post collection. I don't have any idea to resolve this. Can anybody give some suggestions, to solve this.

Comment: How are you planning on matching the selection made via the POST to the category Id? If it's just the `ObjectId`, then can't you just set it? It would probably work if you made the `categoryId` properties a `string` and used the attribute to set their type to a `BSON` `ObjectId`.

Comment: I only want to put into post collection information about post category, and I don't know how put data from collection category to collection post

Comment: Just store the id? It's usually more convenient to interact with `string`s as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes only id from category

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem here, but let's walk through this step-by-step:

First, you'll have to populate the list of available categories, so you'll have to call `FindAll` on your `Category` collection.

Second, you will need to pass this list to the frontend, so you need a view model class that contains some kind of dictionary so you can bind this to a dropdown (`<select>`), for instance, i.e.

```
class PostCreateViewModel
{
     Dictionary<string, string> Categories {get; set;}
     /// ...
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var categories = _categoryService.All();
  var vm = new PostCreateViewModel();
  vm.Categories = categories.ToDictionary(p => p.CategoryId.ToString());
  // etc.
  return View(vm);
}
```

Third, your Post handler should verify that the `CategoryId` is correct:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(Post post)
{
  // Make sure the given category exists. It would be better to have a 
  // PostService with a Create action that checks this internally, e.g.
  // when you add an API or a different controller creates new posts as
  // a side effect, you don't want to copy that logic.
  var category = _categoryService.SingleById(post.CategoryId);
  if(category == null)
      throw new Exception("Invalid Category!");

  // Insert your post in the DB

  // Observe the PRG pattern: Successful POSTs should always redirect:
  return Redirect("foo"); 
}
```

Some details can be tricky, for instance I'm assuming that `post.CategoryId` will be populated through a model binder, but you might have to write a custom model binder for `ObjectId` or use a ViewModel class with a string and parse the string using `ObjectId.Parse`. In general, I'd suggest using ViewModels everywhere and use the help of something like AutoMapper to avoid writing tons of boilerplate copy code.